# Can't open FileEditor with VirtualFile

Tags: java, intellij-idea, filesystems, editor, intellij-plugin

I'm trying to create editor tab in intellij editor manager like that:

```
VirtualFileSystem fileSystem = LocalFileSystem.getInstance();
VirtualFile virtualFile = fileSystem.refreshAndFindFileByPath("path");
FileEditor[] editor = editorsManager.openFile(virtualFile, true);
```

When I did a creation of the file, which I gonna open, manually, there is no issues with editor. But every time I try to get editor of the file I created by this code

```
File tempFile = File.createTempFile("tmp", null);
```

or that

```
new File("path").createNewFile();
```

I've got empty FileEditor array, however, VirtualFile of the file is correct in both cases.

Comment: What are the actual names of the files you're trying to open? IntelliJ will not open a file in the editor if its name doesn't match any of the configured file types.

Comment: Naming thing was fine. I explored, that the issue was about the empty file. It couldn't create FileEditor for the empty one, but with some text in it, all works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I explored, that the issue was about the empty file. It couldn't create FileEditor for the empty one, but with some text in it, all works just fine. So before virtual file creation, fill the file with some default text.